# Sql query - colum2 should match with the column1 of the next selected row

Tags: sql

table

| ID | col1 | coll2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 104A | 103A |
| 2 | 301A | 300A |
| 3 | 103A | 101A |
| 4 | 102A | 101A |
| 5 | 201A | 200A |
| 6 | 101A | 100A |

If i give col1 = 104A in the where condition,output shoud be like

| ID1 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 104A | 103A |
| 3 | 103A | 101A |
| 6 | 101A | 100A |

col2 should match with the next selected row col1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Its SQL DB. Just need sql query for the expected output. Table1 is sample table data. Table 2 is expected output. If i give col1 = '104A' in the where condition of the sql query , table 2 is the expected output.
What i wanted to achieve : Col2 value should match with Col1 value of the next row in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You must `Recursive` produce the desired output

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl t
  WHERE t.col1 = '104A'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.* 
  FROM tbl t join cte c on t.col1 = c.coll2 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c42d940653e23715cc2e9fbbb67719d)